# How to exchange information between 1 parent process and 3 child processes with fork() on c or c++

Tags: c++, c, fork

i need to make a program that can exchange the information between 1 parent and 3 child process created with fork(). The overall task is to send anything from 3-rd child process to 2-nd child and a parent one, and from 2-nd child process to 3-rd. i have the following code to create multiple child processes, but don't understand how to send anything to different processes. Can you help me with this?

```
for (int kid = 0; kid < 3; ++kid) {
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid > 0){
        /* Parent process */
    }
    else{
        /* Child process */
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

for (int kid = 0; kid < 3; ++kid) {
    int status;
    pid_t pid = wait(&status); // kids could be ready in any order
}
```

Comment: please decide for one language. As questions and answers are supposed to be useful for future readers answers would need to provide solutions for C *and* C++ to be complete

Comment: Do you know how to communicate with *one* child process? If not, read up about [pipes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4125/6jd7pe6bo/index.html). If you do: It's the same with three as with one, except you'll need three pipes.

Comment: You have to deal with `IPC` (Inter Process Communication), using either unnamed pipe, named pipe or shared storage. Plz select C or C++ if you want a solution, or search for `IPC` by yourself. You have something nice here [IPC Using Pipes and Msg Queues](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/interprocess-communication-linux-channels)

Comment: Unix domain sockets created with `socketpair()` are handy for two way communication.